# Installing PDO driver in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, pdo

I'm trying to install pdo driver in docker. How do I install it using the below configuration?

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "8089:80"
    volumes:
        - ./code:/code
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
        - php
php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./code:/code
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.26
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=bignibou
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

I also have a Dockerfile which looks like this:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_pgsql pdo_mysql
```